# My workout schedule to get buff w/o gym: pushups, situps, pullups, biking

Tags: workout-routines

I'm working on setting up a routine workout schedule for myself and I'm in need of some input on whether this would work well. Basically I bike 8 miles a day and I want to just alternate pushups, situps and pullups with rest one day a week. I'm looking to get buffer and get a six pack. Right now I can do 25 pushups without stopping and I'm 160lb, so that gives you a sense of my current muscle mass. Does the above plan sound fine?

Comment: What is your height? And, is your goal to get stronger? Or to get buffer?

Comment: @Sancho I'm 6ft, my goal is to get buffer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by gym you mean weights, then yes you do **Not** need weights to get Buffer.
All kinds of body-weight exercises will give you tone, strength and more muscle mass if done properly with proper nutrition.

- For 6 packs, you need both abs exercises with good nutrition (to lower body fat percentage)
- Push ups are amazing for chest, triceps and even core. You need to do **variations**
- Pull ups will give you the V-SHAPE and more muscle on your back. Also, You need to do **variations**

Now i recommend that in addition you :

- [SQUAT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AHyOk0TuXcc)(no need for one legged, but u got the point)
- Do [Burpees](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_Dq_NCzj8M).

**Squatting** not only tones and builds legs muscles, but it empowers ur core, helps you build 6 pack muscles and produce much more growth hormones and thus help u add muscle mass.

Same for **burpees**, it is what i call "explosion" workout. Once you do it u will understand, you will get sore muscles even places where u never knew muscles existed.

**However,** please do these two exercises step by step, with good posture because if you don't take care you might injure urself. 
(i injured my knees because i overdid burpees and i was kinda jumping diagonally not straight..
I got what is called [Plica Syndrome](http://www.eorthopod.com/content/plica-syndrome) and my doctor said i have to rest from leg exercises for 6 weeks. However if you do it properly you 'll see its probably the best bodyweight exericse for power, tone, fat burning and muscle mass increase).

As for  **variations** i highly recommend [mark Lauren's book](http://www.marklauren.com/), it has around 111 bodyweight exercises variations  **with full routines** for different levels (beginner,intermediate,...)

Answer (score 1):

I would replace the 8 mile biking with real-deal sprinting. Biking while allowing you to take on more resistance will be akin to distance running. Distance running is the enemy of getting buff. Sprinting on the other hand builds muscles in the legs. Things like the 100meter and 200 meter dash. You'll need to warm up and stretch though if you're going to sprint. 2x a week would be enough, and for the amount about 1/2 mile to 2miles of sprinting, obviously broken down into components no longer than 400 meters. Note 4x400meters=1mile. When you're strong enough and body-weight exercises done on the pull-up bar, it will add variation to pull-ups and work your abs at the same time. Stuff like this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZeOqM7zt3U

Answer (score 1):

Why not try high interval running in which you sprint for 200m, rest for 30 seconds, and then sprint for another 200m. Do this about 6 times which will help pump your leg. You can do some bridging and leg raises to help build your six pack. A mixture of different pull-ups (wide pull-up, normal pull-up, and close grip pull-ups) of 10 repetitions for 4 sets will also help. After this you may want to pump your chest by doing push-ups (wide push-ups and normal push-ups) for 4 sets where you will push yourself to the maximum rep for every set.